# Changing the value of a hidden field without postbacking

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, hiddenfield

I have a link button, that calls the c# function 'send_Click' when clicked. here is the function:

```
void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "text_alert()", true);
        Response.Write(hidAcrobat.Value);
    }
```

as you can see, it calls a javascript function "text_alert()" which looks like this:

```
function text_alert() {
            var person = prompt("Additional Comments:", "");
            if (person != null && person != "") {
                document.getElementById('hidAcrobat').value = person;
            }
        }
```

which pops a prompt box accepting a user input and setting the value of the hidden field 'hidAcrobat' to this value.

then back to c#, the next line is Response.write(hidAcrobat.Value); 
It writes the default value of the hidAcrobat and NOT the new value which was assigned to it in the prompt box.
I assume its because the page isn't postbacked,
How can I solve this?

Comment: you will have to understand the difference between client side and server side. the value your are changing is on client side. so the value of the variable present in the server side script WILL NOT change until you change it using either a POST BACK or using AJAX

Comment: how can i do that with a post back? thanks

Comment: can you please give the actual case you are using this. i dont understand why are you doing response.write() when you already have the value of the variable on the client side

Comment: I am using respone.write just to see what the value is on the server side. i am trying to update a table item called "meeting" which already has the customerid, customercomments, and professionalid in it. i am showing a prompt box to the professional to get his comments so i can update the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily implemented by Jquery Like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#MainContent_lnkAddToList').live("click", function() {
            var person = prompt("Additional Comments:", "");
            $('[id*="hidAcrobat"]').val(person);
        });
    });
```

After that you can use your hidden field value in any server side event.

For Jquery add reference

Hope It helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Handle onclick event of link button on client side (using javascript) and call `text_alert()` method from the handler.

After executing the client-side event handler, the page posts back and on the server side you can access the hidden variable as you are doing in `send_Click` event handler.

Comment: How can i handle the onclick event on the client side if the button is created dynamically in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can **easily** create a prompt like effect using [ModalPopUp](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) and then easily grab the value on server side.